# moving targets individually in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to move targets individually in pygame.
However when I wrote the code (see below)    package_group.update() updates the shift in the position of all targets for the same amount. How can enter the desired displacement for each target individually?

```
import pygame, sys
import random

class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path, pos_x, pos_y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load((picture_path))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [pos_x,pos_y]
        self.pos_x = pos_x
        self.pos_y = pos_y
        self.speed = 10 #random.randint(5, 20)
            # Move the sprite based on speed
#        self.delta_x = delta_x

    def update(self):

        self.rect.move_ip(self.pos_x, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen_width = 1500
screen_height = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pos_x = 10
pos_y = 300

package_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for n in range(3):
    package = Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1))
    package_group.add(package)
    pack.append(Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1)))
  
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            sys.exit()
    for obj in package_group:
        if package.pos_x < 500: 

    screen.fill((0,0,0))   # clear screen
    package_group.draw(screen)
    package_group.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The package object has a speed variable you can use. Set it in the constructor then use it in the `self.rect.move_ip` call.

Make these changes:

```
class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path, pos_x, pos_y, speed): # add speed parameter
        ........
        self.speed = speed  # save to attribute

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)  # move single sprite
        ......

.......
package = Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1), random.randint(10,40)) # last parameter is speed
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a big mistake in your code. In the following snippet 2 different instances of `Package` are generated, the 1st instance is added to `package_group` and another instance is added to the list `pack`. Hence there are different objects in `package_group` and `pack`

> ```py
> package_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
> for n in range(3):
>    package = Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1))
>    package_group.add(package)
>    pack.append(Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1)))
> ```

It has to be:

```py
package_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
for n in range(3):
    package = Package(r'img.png', 10*pos_x,pos_y+50*(n-1))
    package_group.add(package)
    pack.append(package)
```

---

There is just one mistake in your code. You have to move the object by `self.speed` rather than `self.pos_x`:

<s>`self.rect.move_ip(self.pos_x, 0)`</s>

```py
self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
```

Activate the code which is commented out and sets a random speed:

```py
class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path, pos_x, pos_y):
        # [...]

        self.speed = random.randint(5, 20)

    def update(self):

        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

---

If you want to change the speed randomly, you need to set "speed" by a random value in "update":

```py
class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]
    
    def update(self):

        self.speed = random.randint(5, 20)
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)

        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

---

If you want to define the speed on your own, then you can change the `speed` attribute in the main application by any algorithm you want:

```py
class Package(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,picture_path, pos_x, pos_y):
        # [...]

        self.speed = 10 # initilil speed

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

```py
while True:

    for i, obj in enumerate(package_group):
        obj.speed =  # [...] set the speed of the i-th object in `package_group`
```

Comment: I tried using self.speed, but it does not solve my problem. I want to be able individually change the position of each of three packages according to my algorithm. What can I do to address each of them?

Comment: I did. I will have a different speed for all three packages, but I want to change this speed (position) after every cycle , and I don't want it to be random

Comment: *"I don't want it to be random"* - So who defines the speed?

Comment: @IgorTrofimov I've now added a third possibility to the answer. Furthermore I've spotted a bug in your application. See the 1st section of the answer.